# Bash: Copy a file x times and rename the file automatically from a list in txt

Tags: bash, copy, rename

I have a .txt file containing a list of over 450 lines eg.

```
name_1
name_2
name_3
etc
```

I'd like to copy a file named `file_to_copy.txt` x times (~450) and automatically rename the file I just made to name_1, name_2 and so on, untill I create those ~450 files, each named by a line in the previously mentioned .txt file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you want to say:

```
while read name; do
  cp file_to_copy.txt "${name}";
done < my_text_file_with_filenames.txt
```

Comment: @pythonboxquestion Good to know that it worked.  You might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

try this line:

```
sed 's/^/cp file_to_cp.txt &/' foo.txt|sh
```

remove the `|sh` to see the cp commands generated, with `|sh` to execute those commands.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @devnull's answer, which is probably more canonical than this one, is to use your favorite text editor to insert `cp file_to_copy.txt` in front of all lines in your file and then source it. It is quick and dirty, but it gets the job done quickly if you are not familiar with Bash loops or GNU tools in general.